# Нужна помощь с массивами C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Как определить номер элемента массива. Именно номер, а не сам элемент. В цикле i%2 не работает, пишет, что не удается int преобразовать в bool. Но на c++ это работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замените картинку на код в виде текста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам нужен индекс элемент, то так:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var searchHousse = 5;
    var houses = new int[] {1, 5, 6, 9, 16 };
    var indexOfHouse = Array.IndexOf(houses, searchHousse);

    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}, Index: {1}", houses[indexOfHouse], indexOfHouse);
    if(indexOfHouse % 2 == 0) Console.WriteLine("Apartment index is even!");
    else Console.WriteLine("Apartment index is not even!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (i % 2 != 0) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Зачем у Вас цикл в цикле?

Comment: это для проверки элемента, а мне нужно для проверки номера элемента, то есть {0,1,2,3,...n}

Comment: @ДмитрийДремин Я не могу заглянуть Вам в мозг, так что постарайтесь понятно объяснить, что Вам нужно.

Comment: есть массив, я ввожу туда элементы, у каждого элемента есть свой порядок, который начинается с нуля. Допустим я ввел {9,7,5,3), тогда у {9} будет номер 0, у {7} номер 1 и т.д. и мне нужно определить четность/нечетность НОМЕРА элемента, а не самого элемента

Comment: А цикл в цикле, это ошибка, там должна быть закрывающая скобка перед другим циклом

Comment: @ДмитрийДремин Это как раз то, что делает код в ответе: проверяет четность индекса элемента массива.